# How to configure Nginx for Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, nginx

Currenty we use Apache Tomcat (Version 9) as server. We intend to use Nginx going forward and put Tomcat behind it. 
Our static content at the moment is served by JSP after some internal checks.

Since Nginx is better at serving Static content, we want to use it. But not sure how to prevent public access to the static content.
We want to know what configuration should be used in Nginx so that the static content will be served only if after a certain criteria is met.

Lets say, the URL that is requesting the content would have parameters which the Nginx will redirect to tomcat webapp. The WebApp will validate the parameters and if okay, would let NGinx serve the static file.
How could we accomplish this?

Example.

Lets say the site is at:
/root/www/demo.com (served by tomcat)

images at:
/root/www/images (restricted public access)

demo.com has the JSP pages.
Tomcat serves website at /root/www/demo.com
Now, if an image image1.png at /root/www/images had to be accessed, I would call /root/www/demo.com/ImageShow.jsp?id=1
The JSP would check the id and then return image1.png from the images folder.

If the front server is now replaced by Nginx, and used as proxy for the tomcat server, I want to serve the same image1.png but it has to be processed for some checks by JSP before Nginx returns it to the user.

Hope this explains the requirement.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of request url, what should nginx send to tomcat, and what will tomcat respond

Comment: @DusanBajic, description updated with example.

Comment: Should be doable (at least the nginx part) with [Authentication Based on Subrequest Result](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/)

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic. Its not exactly I wanted, but it did give a direction that can meet our needs.